Which part(s) of this proof of Goodstein's Theorem are not expressible in Peano arithmetic?
EDIT: Noah Schweber helpfully points out that $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is a conservative extension of Peano arithmetic in which certain aspects of my proof not expressible in Peano arithmetic are expressible. So perhaps my question should focus on which part(s) of the proof below are not expressible in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ [or perhaps substitute instead whatever your favourite conservative extension of $\mathsf{PA}$ happens to be].

[In this post, $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.]
I know that Goodstein's Theorem is not provable within Peano arithmetic. But I think I can express the proof of Goodstein's Theorem in a way that feels like it consists entirely of "explicitly constructive" reasoning about natural numbers.
So then, not really knowing anything about formal logic, the question that naturally arises for me is: Which part(s) of the proof below are not expressible in Peano arithmetic?
Lexicographical order
Definition 1. Given non-empty finite totally ordered sets
\begin{align*}
S &= \{s_1 < \ldots < s_N \} \\
T &= \{t_1 < \ldots < t_M \},
\end{align*}
we define the lexicographical order on the set $\,T^S\,$ of functions from $S$ to $T$ by specifying that $f<g$ if and only if there exists $i \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$ such that

every integer $j$ with $i < j \leq N$ has $f(s_j)=g(s_j)$;
$f(s_i) < g(s_i)$.

(It is not hard to show that the lexicographical order on $T^S$ is a total order.)
A representation of hereditary base-$m$ expressions
Recursive Definition 2. For each integer $m \geq 2$:

Let $S_{0,m}$ be a singleton, equipped with its unique total order.
For each integer $k \geq 1$, let $\,S_{k,m}=\{0,\ldots,m-1\}^{S_{k-1,m}}$, equipped with the lexicographical order.

For convenience, we will from now on assume that $S_{0,m}=\{\emptyset\}$.
Recursive Definition 3. For each integer $m \geq 2$:

Define $F_{0,m} \colon S_{0,m} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $F_{0,m}(\emptyset)=0$.
For each integer $k \geq 1$, define $F_{k,m} \colon S_{k,m} \to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$ F_{k,m}(f) = \sum_{h \in S_{k-1,m}} f(h)m^{F_{k-1,m}(h)} $$

Lemma 4. For each integer $m \geq 2$ and each integer $k \geq 1$, $F_{k,m}$ serves as an order-isomorphism from $S_{k,m}$ to $\{0,\ldots,(m\uparrow\uparrow k) - 1\}$.
Proof. Fix $m$. For $k=1$ the result follows immediately from the fact that $m^0=1$. Assuming the result for $k=k_0-1$ (where $k_0 \geq 2$), the result for $k=k_0$ then follows from the fact that the set of base-$m$ expressions of length $N_0:=m\uparrow\uparrow (k_0-1)$ is order-isomorphically mapped by evaluation onto $\{0,\ldots,m^{N_0} - 1\}$. $\quad\square$
Natural embedding of hereditary expressions
Recursive Definition 5. For each integer $m \geq 2$:

Let $\iota_{0,m}$ be the unique function from $S_{0,m}$ to $S_{0,m+1}$.
For each integer $k \geq 1$, define the injective function $\,\iota_{k,m} \colon S_{k,m} \to S_{k,m+1}$ by
$$ \iota_{k,m}(f)(h) = \begin{cases}
f(\iota_{k-1,m}^{-1}(h)) & \text{if } h \in \iota_{k-1,m}[S_{k-1,m}] \\
0 & \text{if } h \not\in \iota_{k-1,m}[S_{k-1,m}]
\end{cases} \qquad \forall \ f \in S_{k,m} \, , \, h \in S_{k-1,m+1}. $$
[This is injective because, for any $f,g \in S_{k,m}$ that disagree at a point $\tilde{h} \in S_{k-1,m}$, we have that $\iota_{k,m}(f)$ and $\iota_{k,m}(g)$ disagree at $\iota_{k-1,m}(\tilde{h})$.]

Lemma 6. For each integer $m \geq 2$ and each integer $k \geq 0$, $\iota_{k,m} \colon S_{k,m} \to S_{k,m+1}$ is an order-embedding.
Proof. Fixing $m$, the result is a straightforward induction in $k$. $\quad\square$
Definition 7. For integers $m_2 > m_1 \geq 2$ and $k \geq 0$, define $\,\iota_{k,m_1,m_2} \colon S_{k,m_1} \to S_{k,m_2}\,$ by
$$ \iota_{k,m_1,m_2} = \iota_{k,m_2-1} \circ \ldots \circ \iota_{k,m_1} $$
Decreasing sequences of hereditary expressions
For each integer $k \geq 0$, let $S_k = \bigcup_{m=2}^\infty S_{k,m}$.
Definition 8. Given an integer $k \geq 0$, a $k$-sequence is a function $\alpha \colon I \to S_k$ for which $I$ is an infinite subset of $\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ and every $m \in I$ has $\alpha(m) \in S_{k,m}$.
Definition 9. Given an integer $k \geq 0$, a $k$-sequence $\alpha \colon I \to S_k$ is called decreasing if for all $m_1,m_2 \in I$ with $m_1 < m_2$, we have
$$ \alpha(m_2) < \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(\alpha(m_1)). $$
The strategy in proof of Goodstein's Theorem will be to construct a way of getting from a decreasing $k$-sequence to a decreasing $(k-1)$-sequence; this ultimately leads down to a decreasing $1$-sequence, which will result in a contradiction.
A basic lemma about embedding of lexicographical order
Lemma 10. For integers $m_2 > m_1 \geq 2$ and $k \geq 1$, if we have $f_1 \in S_{k,m_1}$ and $f_2 \in S_{k,m_2}$ such that
$$ f_2 < \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1), $$
then: (A) the set
$$ H(f_1,f_2) := \{ h \in S_{k-1,m_1} \, : \, f_2(\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h)) < f_1(h) \} $$
is non-empty; (B) letting $h_\ast = \max H(f_1,f_2)$, we have

for all $h \in S_{k-1,m_1}$ with $h>h_\ast$, $\,f_2(\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h)) = f_1(h)$;
for all $h \in S_{k-1,m_2} \setminus \iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}[S_{k-1,m_1}]$ with $h > \iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h_\ast)$, $\,f_2(h)=0$.

Proof. (A) If $H(f_1,f_2)$ is empty then we have that for every $h \in S_{k-1,m_2}$,
$$ f_2(h) \geq \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1)(h), $$
contradicting that $f_2 < \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1)$. (B) By definition, every $h \in S_{k-1,m_1}$ with $h>h_\ast$ has $\,f_2(\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h)) \geq f_1(h)$. So, since $\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}$ is order-preserving, it follows that for every $h \in S_{k-1,m_2}$ with $h>\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h_\ast)$, $f_2(h) \geq \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1)(h)$. Since $f_2 < \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1)$, it then follows that for every $h \in S_{k-1,m_2}$ with $h>\iota_{k-1,m_1,m_2}(h_\ast)$, $f_2(h) = \iota_{k,m_1,m_2}(f_1)(h)$, giving the result. $\quad\square$
Proof of Goodstein's Theorem
Suppose for a contradiction that we have an integer $p \geq 1$ such that the Goodstein sequence starting at $p$ does not terminate. Let $k \geq 1$ be an integer such that $p<2\uparrow\uparrow k$. Due to Lemma 4, a simple recursion enables us to construct a decreasing $k$-sequence $\alpha \colon \{2,3,4,\ldots\} \to S_k$ such that the Goodstein sequence is given by $\big( F_{k,m}(\alpha(m)) \big)_{\!m \geq 2}$.
We now recursively construct a finite list
$$ ( \ \ \alpha_0 \colon I_0 \to S_k \quad , \quad \alpha_1 \colon I_1 \to S_{k-1} \quad , \quad \ldots \quad , \quad \alpha_N \colon I_N \to S_{k-N} \ \ ) $$
for some $N \leq k$, where for each $j \in \{0,\ldots,N\}$, $\alpha_j$ is a $(k-j)$-sequence, as follows:

Firstly, $I_0=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ and $\alpha_0=\alpha$.
Now for each integer $j \in \{0,\ldots,k\}$ for which $(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_j)$ exists, do the following procedure:

If $j=k$, or if $j<k$ and $\alpha_j$ is not decreasing, then take $N=j$.
If $j<k$ and $\alpha_j$ is decreasing, then recursively define sequences $(m_{j,n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(h_{j,n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by


$m_{j,0} = \min I_j\,$,
for each integer $n \geq 0$, writing
\begin{align*}
H_{j,n} :=& \bigcup_{\substack{m \in I_j \\ m > m_{j,n}}} H(\alpha_j(m_{j,n}) \, , \, \alpha_j(m)) \\
=& \ \{ h \in S_{k-j-1,m_{j,n}} \, : \, \exists \, m \in I_j \text{ with } m > m_{j,n} \text{ s.t. } \alpha_j(m)(\iota_{k-j-1,m_{j,n},m}(h)) < \alpha_j(m_{j,n})(h) \}
\end{align*}
[which is non-empty by Lemma 10(A)], let
$$ h_{j,n} = \max \, H_{j,n} \, , $$
and writing
$$ x_{j,n} := \min\{ \alpha_j(m)(\iota_{k-j-1,m_{j,n},m}(h_{j,n})) \, : \, m \in I_j \text{ with } m > m_{j,n} \}, $$
let
$$ m_{j,n+1} = \min\{ m \in I_j \text{ with } m > m_{j,n} \, : \, \alpha_j(m)(\iota_{k-j-1,m_{j,n},m}(h_{j,n})) = x_{j,n} \} $$


and define $I_{j+1}=\{m_{j,n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and
\begin{align*}
&\alpha_{j+1} \,\colon\, I_{j+1} \to S_{k-j-1} \\
&\alpha_{j+1}(m_{j,n}) = h_{j,n}.
\end{align*}


If $N=k$ then we have in particular that $\alpha_{k-1}$ is a decreasing $1$-sequence; so, for each integer $n \geq 1$, letting $m_n$ denote the $n$-th value in $I_{k-1}$ and letting $y_n=\alpha_{k-1}(m_n)(\emptyset)$, the sequence $(y_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of natural numbers. But then there is no possible value for the $(y_1+2)$-th term in this sequence, and so we have a contradiction.
So to complete the proof, it only remains to show that $N=k$, which we will do by induction. The base step is to show that $N>0$: this is immediate from the facts that $0<k$ and $\alpha$ is decreasing.
Now suppose we have an integer $j_0$ with $0 \leq j_0 \leq k-2$ such that $N>j_0$; we need to show that $N>j_0+1$. For this it is sufficient to show that $\alpha_{j_0+1}$ is decreasing. To do this, it is sufficient just to verify Definition 9 for consecutive pairs of integers in $I_{j_0+1}$, since then (due to transitivity of $<$) a simple induction argument will give that $\alpha_{j_0+1}$ satisfies Definition 9 in full. Consecutive pairs of integers in $I_{j_0+1}$ take the form $(m_{j_0,n} \, , \, m_{j_0,n+1})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
So we need to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ h_{j_0,n+1} < \iota_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n},m_{j_0,n+1}}(h_{j_0,n}). $$
Fix any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For convenience, let $\bar{\iota}=\iota_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n},m_{j_0,n+1}}$; so we need to show that $h_{j_0,n+1} < \bar{\iota}(h_{j_0,n})$. Since $h_{j_0,n+1}$ is defined as the maximum of $H_{j_0,n+1}$, we need to show that every $h \in S_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n+1}}$ with $h \geq \bar{\iota}(h_{j_0,n})$ lies outside of $H_{j_0,n+1}$. We split into the following three cases:

$h>\bar{\iota}(h_{j_0,n})$ and $h \in \bar{\iota}[S_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n}}]$;
$h>\bar{\iota}(h_{j_0,n})$ and $h \not\in \bar{\iota}[S_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n}}]$;
$h=\bar{\iota}(h_{j_0,n})$.

Case 1: Let $h'=\bar{\iota}^{-1}(h)$. For any $m \in I_{j_0}$ with $m>m_{j_0,n+1}$, Lemma 10(B) applied to both the pair $\big(\alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n}) \, , \, \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n+1})\big)$ and the pair $\big(\alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n}) \, , \, \alpha_{j_0}(m)\big)$ gives that
$$ \alpha_{j_0}(m)(\iota_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n+1},m}(h)) = \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n})(h') = \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n+1})(h). $$
Hence $h \not\in H_{j_0,n+1}$.
Case 2: For any $m \in I_{j_0}$ with $m>m_{j_0,n+1}$, Lemma 10(B) applied to both the pair $\big(\alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n}) \, , \, \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n+1})\big)$ and the pair $\big(\alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n}) \, , \, \alpha_{j_0}(m)\big)$ gives that
$$ \alpha_{j_0}(m)(\iota_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n+1},m}(h)) = 0 = \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n+1})(h). $$
Hence $h \not\in H_{j_0,n+1}$.
Case 3: For any $m \in I_{j_0}$ with $m>m_{j_0,n+1}$, we have
$$ \alpha_{j_0}(m)(\iota_{k-j_0-1,m_{j_0,n+1},m}(h)) \geq x_{j_0,n} = \alpha_{j_0}(m_{j_0,n+1})(h). $$
Hence $h \not\in H_{j_0,n+1}$.
So we are done.

I have not read most of this, but this jumps out at me:  The strategy in proof of Goodstein's Theorem will be to construct a way of getting from a decreasing k
-sequence to a decreasing (k−1)
-sequence.   This makes me wonder if  you are proving something for some unspecified $k$, when you actually need it for all $k$.

You define a sequence of infinite sets $I_0, I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_k$ of arbitrary length $k$ by recursion, each such infinite set being defined from a previous one by a formula involving unbounded quantifiers. This is not the sort of thing which can be carried out in Peano Arithmetic.

Peano Arithmetic doesn't come with a built-in ability to recursively define infinite sets in this manner. If you try to encode this kind of recursive definition of a sequence of infinite sets in the same way you might encode recursive definitions of sequences of natural numbers, you will find yourself wanting to use quantifiers which quantify over all finite sequences of infinite lists, a kind of quantification not available in Peano Arithmetic.

Put more simply, there is no notion of a variable of type "arbitrary subset of the natural numbers" in Peano Arithmetic. And thus you cannot work with these $I_0, I_1, \ldots, I_k$ in the manner you might expect.

@SridharRamesh Thank you very much for your comments. I'm not sure what you mean by "arbitrary length $k$" - to be clear, both the number $k$ and the starting set $I_0$ are explicitly obtained from the starting number $p$ in the Goodstein sequence. If I just wanted to get as far as defining $I_1$ from $I_0$, would that be possible in Peano arithmetic?

@SridharRamesh While true, that's not the fatal issue: $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{PA}$ and can treat sets directly. So something else has to break.

@NoahSchweber But $\text{ACA}_0$ cannot undertake recursive definitions of such classes---this requires ATR. That is, with ACA we can one-off define each class, but we can't define the sequence of them by recursion.  (But I haven't read the OP, so this might not be relevant...)

@JoelDavidHamkins Thank you for the comment. Is my construction just to get from $I_0$ to $I_1$ possible in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$? [Well, I'd only ask for an answer in the unlikely event that you have time to read through my long and tedious proof :) ]

Do any of the answers here help? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138875/why-do-stacked-quantifiers-in-pa-correspond-to-ordinals-up-to-epsilon-0/139015#139015

I haven't grokked all the details of your proof, but it does seem that you are defining the classes $I_j$ by an arithmetic recursion, which would not be possible in PA or $\text{ACA}_0$, but require $\text{ATR}_0$, which implies Con(PA). You can't say that $k$ is really standard finite, since then you are not proving the $\forall p$ claim, and not every $p$ in a nonstandard model of PA will be bounded that way by a standard $k$. So you really do need to consider that $k$ is possibly nonstandard, and then you seem really to be using ATR.  (But again, I have not read all details of your proof.)

Also, your title is about expressibility, but the key issue is provability. Of course none of the class stuff is expressible in PA, even if it is in second-order arithmetic, and then the question is what are the second-order resources you are using. And since it is a giant induction/recursion, $\text{ATR}_0$ seems likely a good default. You can't fall back on the idea that $k$ is bounded by the instance you consider, since Goodstein's theorem is a universal claim, so the instance might be nonstandard in a nonstandard model.

@JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I wasn't trying to say that the proof worked, simply that the obstacle had to be more subtle than referring to sets. And at a glance I believe you're right about the fatal point.

The issue I raised in my first two comments is not about simply referring to sets. Rather, as I said, it is specifically about defining these sets via recursion, which would require defining sets using quantification over sets. My third comment glosses this in terms of not having variables of set type, for "tl;dr" purposes, but I think what I have said in my first two comments is accurate about the fatal point. The last sentence of my second comment says specifically that the issue is the inability to quantify over sets while defining sets, an issue just as present in ACA_0 as in PA.

The concern about $k$ being an "arbitrary length" is like so: One can unroll the recursions to define $I_k$ for any particular standard natural $k$. You can write out a definition of $I_0$, and then manually write out another definition of $I_1$, and then manually write out yet a third definition for $I_2$, etc. Individually, these are definable, in isolation. But you can't in one proof write infinitely many such individually-tailored definitions covering each possible value of $k$.

What you need to recursively define to carry out this proof is the full binary relation $R(k, x) = x \in I_k$ (in other words, the set ${(k, x) \mid k \in \mathbb{N}, x \in I_k}$), and this is the sort of recursive definition unavailable in PA or ACA_0, though one can do it in stronger set theories.

Because your argument involves arithmetical classes at several points, as you noticed, it is not directly expressible in the first-order language of $\newcommand\PA{\text{PA}}\PA$, although as Noah mentioned in the comments it is naturally expressible in the language of second-order arithmetic, which allows for both numbers and sets (classes) of numbers.
The theory $\newcommand\ACA{\text{ACA}}\ACA_0$ ensures the existence of all arithmetically definable sets of numbers, and is conservative over $\newcommand\PA{\text{PA}}\PA$. And many of the sets of numbers that you want to prove exist are indeed arithmetically definable, and thus would exist in $\ACA_0$.
However, it seems to me that you are also defining classes by recursion. For example, in the center of your argument you define the classes $I_j$ by recursion, as Sridhar Ramesh mentioned in the comments. In general, this is not possible even in $\ACA_0$, but requires the stronger theory $\newcommand\ATR{\text{ATR}}\ATR_0$, which allows for arithmetic recursions of that sort.
Consider for example the Tarskian recursive definition of truth, which is a simple arithmetic recursion on formulas — we define truth on the atomic formulas, and then explain how truth propogates through Boolean connectives and quantifiers. This is all arithmetically expressible, to define how truth extends from simpler formulas to the next level of complexity. But $\ACA_0$ does not prove that there is a truth predicate for arithmetic truth, in light of Tarski's theorem on the nondefinability of truth. Namely, there can be no arithmetically definable truth predicate for arithmetic truth. And therefore we cannot in general undertake arithmetical class recursions in $\ACA_0$.
It will not help you to argue that you require only a standard finite $k$ many steps in your recursion. That may be true, for any standard finite $p$, but however, we are discussing proving the Goodstein theorem, which is the universal claim about all $p$, not just each case separately. So you don't really know that $p$ is standard in the general case and therefore you can't know that $k$ is standard either.
But it can be undertaken in $\ATR_0$. This theory, however, is not conservative over $\ACA_0$, and implies $\text{Con}(PA)$ and so on. Your recursion is merely length $\omega$, which is a fragment of $\ATR_0$, but this is the same fragment used to define the truth predicate, so it also is not conservative.
Disclaimer: I haven't actually gone through all the details of your original post, and so please forgive me if I have misunderstood.

Thank you very much! The question that this naturally raises for me is then: Suppose I just want to prove that the Goodstein sequence starting at, say, 15 terminates.

If I re-wrote my argument (beginning "Proof of Goodstein's Theorem") with $3$ in place of $k$, and instead of a recursion I constructed $(\alpha_1,I_1)$ from $(\alpha_0,I_0)$ and showed that $\alpha_1$ is a decreasing $2$-sequence - all in exactly the manner as I have written - and then repeated the argument to construct $(\alpha_2,I_2)$ from $(\alpha_1,I_1)$ and show that $\alpha_2$ is a decreasing $1$-sequence, giving a contradiction, would this still proof still be expressible in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$?

@JulianNewman The fact that the Goodstein sequence starting from a fixed standard number (such as $15$) terminates is a true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, and therefore it is provable already in Robinson’s arithmetic.

@JulianNewman Right, perhaps it helps to mention that every single specific instance of Goodstein's theorem is provable in PA already (and much weaker systems as Emil mentions). What is independent of PA is the universal claim. This is why in my answer I had emphasized the point about not knowing that $p$ and $k$ are standard finite.

Thank you; to clarify, in my comment, I wasn't asking if each instance of Goodstein's Theorem is provable in PA [since I would assume that just manually checking the numbers in the Goodstein sequence until it terminates would count as a proof in PA] - I was essentially asking [as also in my question to Sridhar Ramesh] if my approach of constructing $I_1$ from the infinite set $I_0$ is doable in ACA$_0$ (and if so, then can I get a proof of a given case by then constructing $I_2$ from $I_1$, and so on until the requisite $I_k$, and then concluding in the manner that I did in my post).

Although I've now just seen that Sridhar wrote a couple of further comments yesterday that may be indicating a positive answer to my question.

Yes, specific arithmetic class recursions of standard finite length can be undertaken in $\text{ACA}_0$, since the recursion can be done in the metatheory, and one is just using arithmetic comprehension at each step.
